# How is it that my output is different when executing script in ISE than console? String find and replace

Tags: powershell, html-parsing

Hi everyone am very new at powershell so am hoping I can get some guidance. I created a script to cleanup an html file so essentially I modify the file to have all the  tags in individual lines and then I remove the tags so only the final file only has the content that is between the tags. this is what my code looks like

```
$var_test10 = Get-Content Init.txt -raw
$var_test10.Replace("<text","`r`n<text").Replace("</text>","</text>`r`n") > test2.txt
Get-Content test2.txt | Select-String -AllMatches -Pattern "(<text.*<\/text>)" > test3.txt
$var_f = (Get-Content test3.txt)  -replace "<text.*?>",""
$var_f.Replace("</text>","") > Final.txt
Remove-Item * -Include test*.txt
```

but when I run the script from the PS ISE sample of my end result looks like so

```
In service
72.38 F
```

in the PS console some of my outputs look like so, a new line character is added so <text.*> is not removed

```
<text fill="" x="5" y="45" font-size="20" text-anchor="start" style="transform: scale(1); transform-origin: left
```

```
center;">72.38 F
```

here is a sample of the raw html file I just grabbed the first section I could find. the file is massive `<text x="2" y="13" font-size="8.25" fill="#FFF" stroke="none" transform="translate(3.407 22.17)">+</text><text x="2" y="13" font-size="8.25" fill="#FFF" stroke="none" transform="translate(5.407 2.17)">-</text><path fill="none" d="M.407 30.67h3M.407 10.67h3M46.407 20.67h-3"></path>`

I don't quite yet understand what is happening when running the script in the different environments.

Thanks in advance

I did consider creating a new regex like so (?<=>)(.*)(?=</text>)to just select the text within the tags but I don't remember it working.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving aside that you don't need intermediate files to solve your problem:

The problem is that the following call's output depends on the *size of the console window*:

```
Get-Content test2.txt | 
  Select-String -AllMatches -Pattern "(<text.*<\/text>)" > test3.txt
```

Replace it with:

```
(
  Get-Content test2.txt | 
  Select-String -AllMatches -Pattern "(<text.*<\/text>)"
).Line > test3.txt
```

That is, ensure that only the *line text* is saved to the file, as reported in the `.Line` property of the [`[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo]`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo) instances that [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) outputs.

---

Without `.Line`, `>` (in effect an alias for [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file)), the `MatchInfo` instances are formatted *as they would print to the display*, which involves *line-wrapping* the content of matching lines that are too wide for the current console width.